# Signal Protocol Key Length

Tags: networking, public-key-encryption, signal-protocol

I am learning about the Signal protocol and eventually hope on implementing it in one of my projects. I haven't been able to find the length of:

- Identity key IK
- Signed prekey SPK
- Prekey signature Sig(IK, Encode(SPK))
  -One-time prekeys (OPK1, OPK2, OPK3, ...)

Does anyone know how many bits or bytes each key is?